# Uploading and downloading files from a list type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using an ASP.NET FileUpload to upload files to the server. How to upload it to the rootfolder of my project. I want to add the files to a collection or list of files to be shown on the webpage in the form of gridview. Each file should have a link to itself in the list So that it could be downloaded by the click-if desired. The gridview will also have a delete column so that I can delete any of the corresponding file-as desired. Can anyone help me to achieve this easily-without javascript or ajax

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

Simple way: create a sub-folder where you'll place your files and use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx) to list them.

Complex (but better) way: create a sub-folder where you'll save your files, outside of the web site, when a file is uploaded write an entry into a database, specifying the file's name (and maybe some other useful informations, e.g. size, type, etc), in your page you list the database entries, and when a user clicks on one of the links you serve the files through an ASHX handler. This way you have access control on who can download the files, and can track statistics.